# NTLM auth in multithread via HttpClient

Tags: c#, multithreading, http, web, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to create an application which will continously send many http requests to one web endpoint which uses NTLM authentification (via login and password). To optimize the app, it was decided to use multithread execution, so I can send many http requests simultaneously. I'm using following code:

```
private string DoGetRequestWithCredentials(Uri callUri, NetworkCredential credentials)
{
    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler {Credentials = credentials})
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue mtqhv;
            MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.TryParse(
                "application/json;odata=verbose", out mtqhv);//success

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(mtqhv);
            client.Timeout = RequestTimeout.Value;

            var result = client.GetAsync(callUri).Result;
            result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }
    }
}
```

Code works fine in a single thread, but when I enable multithread, I'm starting to receive *401 UNAUTHORIZED* exceptions.

My suggestion why this happens is because some of requests in multithread are trying to be executed between consiquential NTLM calls.

Is my assumption correct?

How can I avoid this situations without locking the method? Because I really want requests to be sent simultaneously

Comment: Better use "true" async instead of `.Result`.

Comment: That should be perfectly fine if a rather stupid implementation (those async methods are async dir a reason). The problem might be on the server side.

Comment: `HTTPClient` can be used in multithreaded fashion, without creating it each time